# Tooltip mouseover on specific word in a sentence. for example language translation

Tags: javascript

I am so sorry. for not knowing english. you can see the question from the picture. How can I do with javascript?

[image]

Comment: please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before. you need to post  your code or what did you tried .

Answer (score 0):

Surround the word you want with a span, then use event onMouseEnter to show tooltip and onMouseLeave to hide it.

You can use a data attribute or title attribute of the span to get the text to place in the tooltip.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I am trying.